# Is it possible to use my PC's fingerprint in C#?

Tags: testing, arduino, software-design, fingerprint, biometrics

I am developing a software which needs a fingerprint ID to get access or login. Meanwhile, I can't work with Arduino and fingerprint sensors, because There is no mushc time ahead. I am thinking about using the integrated-Fingerfrint of my laptop to get Finger's ID. Is it possible to do such operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

The long answer is you will need a lot of things to do so.  The first is you will need to find out which fingerprint scanner you have in your laptop.  Then you will need to find out what SDK's that device manufacturer offers.  Most will provide a image acquisition API that you can use to capture images.  Most of those SDKs are going to have a C api that you will need to wrap in PInvoke calls.

Once you have images you will need an algorithm.  There is a chance that the Device manufacturer sells an SDK that includes an algorithm, if not there are other companies that just build algorithms that you can purchase.

NIST also has an algorithm that is free, but it only has a C interface so again, you will have to do some work.

You might want to checkout https://www.fulcrumbiometrics.com.  They support a large number of device manufactures and may be able to help you find what you are looking for.